# autorefresh Graph in Odoo each X seconds?

Tags: javascript, odoo

I'd like to redefine a JS function which is in the `graph_widget.js` file.

To clarify,  I want to refresh a graph in my own module, but when modifying the 
`graph_widget.js` file, all the graphs in each module refresh every (x seconds).

Any help will be appreciated.

I tried the `autorefresh` attribute, but it seems that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use in java script set Timeout Method more detail to see in jquery website

```
setTimeout(function() {
  canRequest = true;
}, 500);
```